# Conveying the idea of "stay tuned"

Tags: expressions, anglais, expressions-idiomatiques

In one course I wanted to say to my students:

> More advanced things to come; stay tuned!

I wasn't sure if the translation " restez à l'écoute" can be used idiomatically in this context.

> Des choses plus avancées à venir; restez à l'écoute!

What other expressions convey the same idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oui! *Rester à l'écoute* me semble approprié.

Le *tuned* rappelant évidemment le *tuner* qu'il faut accorder sur une fréquence précise pour capter une station de radio et suivre une émission... pour garder leurs auditeurs captifs, les animateurs de radio ajoutaient : *sur la fréquence*.

L'explosion des radios-libres dans les années 80 (dont les étudiants d'alors étaient tous fans) nous faisait d'ailleurs, par dérision, le rajouter dans le sens figuré tel qu'utilisé par l'OP :

*On peut s'attendre à des découvertes spectaculaires, restez à l'écoute sur la fréquence.*

On pourrait aussi activer d'autres sens :

*Garder l’œil* dessus. / *Garder un œil* dessus.

Et d'autres verbes liés à l'attention / l'éveil :

*Surveiller* (les) / *Rester à l'affût* / *Rester branché*/ *Suivre (les) de près*

Et moi et mon a.cos(w.t)... on aimait bien évidemment : *rester en phase*. ;-)

Comment: Super ! Merci pour cette réponse ! Je ne sais pas si les étudiants de nos jours écoutent de la radio mais ça n'est pas une question pour FSE:-)!

Comment: *Restez à l'antenne* se dit bien dans cette situation aussi me semble-t-il

Comment: @Lyzvaleska : Peut-être. À mon époque, cette locution s'entendait plus destinée à ceux qui tenaient l'émetteur / le micro et donc, par extension, ceux dont on attendait que la suite vienne, les **acteurs**, qu'à ceux qui étaient du coté du récepteur et donc, par extension,  en attente (passive) de la suite.

Comment: Si tu veux rester en phase, il faudrait peut-être ajouter quelque chose a w.t :-)

Comment: @Unfrancophone !lol! Oui! Tous les ans, y a bien 2.ℿ qui s'ajoutent malgré moi mais... je sais encore faire de sorte qu'il n'y paraisse rien... ;-)

Answer (score 1):

L'animateur de télévision juste avant une coupure pub dit parfois:

> Restez avec nous!